# How to make a delay in a keypress in pygame?

Tags: python, time, pygame, delay

I am making a platformer and to make an easy version of gravity, I need to make it so when I jump(spacebar) after 2 seconds or so gravity turns back on. Basically 'ychange' changes the y axis position of the character per frame (if ychange = 3, it goes down 3 pixels per frame). It is always set to 6 so he falls 6 frames per frame until he hits something that has a collision, to make him jump ychange is set to -6 or -7, which makes him raise 6 or 7 pixels a frame.

My question is, how can I delay switching from ychange = -6 to ychange = 6 for a jump

Ex:

WHEN JUMP:
ychange = -6
DELAY FOR 2-3 SECONDS
ychange = 6

I have obviously tried time.sleep and pygame.time.wait but they literally pause the program until the wait is over which obviously is not good.

The code for the jump is:

```
while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get(): # Binds
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                xchange -= 3
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                xchange += 3
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE: # SPACEBAR/JUMP
                ychange = -6
                time.sleep(2)
                ychange = 6
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a or event.key == pygame.K_d:
                xchange = 0
```

They "if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE" is the jump part, the rest are other binds.

That is an example of it with time.sleep command which pauses the whole program until the delay is finished.

Any ideas?

Restatement:

Problem: Delay pauses the program

Tried: time.sleep, pygame.time.wait

Question: How do I get a delay that will not pause the whole program

Comment: Have you tried using a threaded approach to changing the value after a while?

Comment: Give me an example of what you mean please.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html - you create a separate processing unit that will not be run on the main thread. It can then contain the sleep, and will not block the other one. As long as `ychange` is a module-level constant, it should be modifiable in the child thread.

Comment: Oh! I understand what you mean, I do that with pygame music.

Comment: There you are - remember to factor in threading and multiprocessing whenever possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `pygame.time.get_ticks()` to get the time when the player presses space and then set a boolean flag to true. Then get the time once a frame until 2 seconds have passed from the original time, at which point you set ychange to 6 and set the flag to false again.

Alternatively look up threading like one of the comments suggests.

Pseudocode:

```
flag = False; # do this before the game loop starts

if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
    # checking flag prevents resetting the timer
    if flag == False and event.key == pygame.K_w:
        starttime = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        ychange = -6
        flag = True

# wait 2000 milliseconds before executing this 
if flag == True and pygame.time.get_ticks() - starttime >= 2000:
    ychange = 6
    flag = False
```

Comment: Can you type up an example of what you mean? I don't understand what to do after typing pygame.time.get_ticks()

Comment: Hm. I have tried this, no errors, but no difference, id print the code but it is pretty much exactly the same as yours. Any ideas? I need to add jumping in the game as it is a platformer

Comment: Make sure you initialize flag before the first if statement, otherwise I think it'll go out of scope between the if statements.

Comment: Nevermind, it shouldn't go out of scope, but you want to initialize it before checking either way. Try using `print` statements to check which code gets executed.

Comment: The problem seems to be the "and" part of the 2nd statement. I removed it and i was able to continue the print statement, but since there was no time delay he just stood still. How could we fix that?

Comment: I got it to work, but it only works when i make him turn in the other direction whilst jumping. W

Comment: Hmm same result with the fix. I dont understand.

Comment: It basically doesnt work until a 2nd event is invoked. Example would be  when 'jumping' i am holding d. I press it again or press a and then it prints out starttime and i fall. Thats what i need to fix.

Comment: Fixed it! I places the 2nd part outside if the event loop